# Font subsetting problems

Tags: css, web, fonts, font-face

I have a font I want to use on my website. I live in a country where we use characters like "š,ř,č,ž,ě" and so on. I need those characters. When I open up Photoshop and use my font, it works with these (latin-extended I guess) chars without a problem.

When I use Font Squirrel to generate the @font-face, I set it all up to include almost every character possible. Still, in the character demo they provide in the download, the special-encoding characters are missing.

What could be the problem? Any solutions? I'm 100% sure the font supports the chars, but it seems Font Squirrel disregards that support. Or I'm setting something not the way I'm supposed to. Any alternatives? Thanks!

Comment: Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org) includes a font editor. I suggest you load up the font and take a look at the character mappings.

Comment: Again, how could I use the characters if there were none. I don't need inscape for that. The problem is with the font conversion. Is there any way I could do that on my own?

Comment: If the font doesn't contain those characters it is still possible to make copies of existing characters and modify them in inkscape, then map them to characters. I used it to make a custom glyph font for icons. It seems like you're adding accents to existing roman characters, so it is not too hard. What is it for, Latvian?

Comment: For the third time, I'm sure the font CONTAINS the characters. I'm using them in Photoshop right now. The conversion cuts them off. I need a better converter. It's for Czech.

Comment: Try: http://onlinefontconverter.com/

Comment: Do you know for sure that the CONVERTED fonts have missing glyphs? Open the converted fonts in an font editor and inspect the 'missing' glyphs. It could be that there is nothing wrong with the conversion. Is your HTML UTF-8 encoded and does it contain `<meta charset="utf-8">`?

Comment: I checked both. The converted fonts don't have the glyphs. And yes, I do have that meta tag.

Comment: I'm sure all glypgs would survive the converstion if you select "no subsetting".